# extract as if a key value pair in bash

Tags: bash

The other day I stumbled upon a question on SO. If I wanted to extract the value of `HOSTNAME` in /etc/sysconfig/network which contains

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=foo
```

now I can do grep and cut to get the `foo` but there was some bash magic involved for a similar issue. I don't know what to search for that and I can't seem to find the question now. it involved something like `#{HOSTNAME}` . As if it was treating `HOSTNAME` as a key and `foo` as a value.

Answer (score 2):

If that configuration file is compatible with shell syntax, simply include it as a shell script. IIRC the files in `/etc/sysconfig` on Red Hat-like distributions are indeed designed to be parsable by a shell. Note that this means that

- If shell special characters may end up in a variable's value, they must be properly quoted. For example, `var="value with spaces"` requires the quotes. `var="with\$dollar"` requires the backslash.
- The script may run arbitrary code that will be executed, so this is only ok if you trust its content.

If these assumptions are valid, then you can go the simple route:

```
. /etc/sysconfig/network
echo "$HOSTNAME"
```

Regarding the quoting and braces, see [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote).

Comment: hmm! Interesting, not what i was looking for but interesting!

Comment: @swair That's the only thing I can think of that would remotely qualify as “bash magic”. If the syntax was really `#{HOSTNAME}`, that would be some unusual tool, not a utility that you can expect to find on every RH installation.

Comment: An added level of protection, as long as the script doesn't muck around with the filesystem (`rm`, `mv`, etc) is to run the script in a subshell: `( . /etc/sysconfig/network; echo "$HOSTNAME")`